# How find words and strip the words after it?

Tags: php, string, substring

```
$string = 'hello world php is a bla bla..';
```

How to keep 'hello world php', by finding if the string contains any 'is', and then remove all the characters after it?

I can't use substr because the occurrence of 'is' is not consistent, also it may be repeatable. How to catch the first one?

Comment: [strpos](http://php.net/strpos)?

Comment: give more examples of source and target strings.  Your question is very vague ("the occurrence of 'is' is not consistent, also it may be repeatable" ???)

Comment: @colminator means it could be 'hello asp hello is my mother and also is etc', as u can see 'is' occurred twice..

Comment: so for "hello asp hello is my mother and also is etc"  you want to map it to "hello asp hello". Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use explode:

```
<?php

$string = 'hello world php is a bla bla..';

$string = explode(' is ', $string);

echo $string[0];

?>
```

Read more at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: what if my string contain no 'is'? will $string = $string[0] return error?

Comment: @JamesLemon no, return the original $string . try with the code

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer is this good to check for massive check? for example instead of 'is' alone, I have few others words too...

Comment: @EltonJamie yes, just try your others words ;-)

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I mean how is it look like if i have multiple words.

Comment: @EltonJamie can you post another question with your situacion? You can use and array and iterate.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179760/find-words-and-abolish-characters-after-it

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
$string = 'hello world php is a bla bla..';
    $str= substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "is"));
```

also you can use preg_replace,

```
$str = preg_replace('/ is.*/', '', $string );
```

Comment: `strpos` can return `false` if the string is not found.

Comment: why the 'is' contain a dot behind it? what if the word I want to use is 'feat.'? then add two dots? what's the dot for?

Comment: '/ is.*/' this part tells get string after "is".

Comment: @EltonJamie the dot is a special regular expression symbol that matches any character the * matches 0 or more of that any character.  So " is.*" basicly means, match anything after the first " is" *and* everythng after it. That "match" is then replaced by the second argument ('') - so essentially everything after the " is" - including the " is" is removed.

Comment: I see, what if I have multiple words instead of ' is' alone? and some of the word contain dot at the back like 'feats'..

Comment: you can use that too in preg_replace if you have concern then you use first method of doing