# How find words and abolish (delete) characters after it based in a list?

Tags: php, arrays, string, substring

If I want to check 'php' exist in a string and delete the words after it I could just use:

```
$string = 'hello world php is a bla bla..';
$string = explode(' php ', $string);
echo $string[0];
```

But what if I have multiple words instead of just 'php'? For example few song name below has 'feats','feat','ft','ft.'.. that's four of them.

I want to make like 'sia - elastic feat brunos mars' become just 'sia - elastic'.

Comment: try `str_replace('php', '' ,$string)`

Comment: @NarendraSisodia by using explode I can do the same thing but how about multiple words? I do not want to write duplicated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that you need:

```
<?php

$string = 'sia - elastic feat brunos mars';

$array = array('feats', 'feat', 'ft', 'ft.');

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
  $out = explode(' ' . $array[$i] . ' ', $string);
  if (count($out) > 1) {
       break;
  }   
}

echo $out[0];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 $string = 'hello world php is a bla bla..';
 $string_before = strstr($string, 'php', true);
```

this will check for the first occurrence of the string 'php'.. and remove the rest after that.